# React DnD with react-konva

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd, react-konva

I have implemented react DnD to copy and drag elements and drop in to a container. Now I want to implement react-konva to create an arrow between them. It would be really helpful if someone an help me in direction and give some pointers of how to use react DnD and react Konva together.

Comment: Wants to know the answer too

Comment: Did you figure it out?